# How to make Unity3D Camera focusing on one area?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my Unity3D project, I have a board created dynamically (using c#) and located on the screen as follow:

```
0 < x < 12
0 < z < 12
y = -1
```

How can I make the camera focusing on the board and make it centered for different screen resolutions and for different platforms?

Comment: just to clarify the question, you want to see the full board on different resolutions, am i right? so, if the resolution is smaller, you don't want the board to be clipped?

Comment: That's exactly what i want.

Comment: I think only you have to adjust the Camera `FieldOfView` depending on current screen ration and default screen ration

Comment: @FouadWahabi can you write a complete well organized answer so I can understand things much better?

Comment: may this helps : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_of_view_in_video_games#Field_of_view_calculations

Comment: and this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22015697/how-to-keep-2-objects-in-view-at-all-time-by-scaling-the-field-of-view-or-zy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example :

```
    using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

/**
 * This class attempts to force VERT- Field of view scaling.
 * By default, Unity uses the HOR+ technique.
 * 
 * http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_of_view_in_video_games#Scaling_methods
 */

[ExecuteInEditMode]
[RequireComponent (typeof(Camera))]
public class VertMinusCameraFOV : MonoBehaviour {

    public float designTimeVerticalFieldOfView = 60;
    public int designTimeWidth = 1280; // default screen width
    public int designTimeHeight = 720; // default screen height

    private float hFOVInRads;

    private int prevWidth;
    private int prevHeight;

    void Start () {

        prevWidth = designTimeWidth;
        prevHeight = designTimeHeight;

        float aspectRatio = (float) designTimeWidth / (float) designTimeHeight;
        float vFOVInRads = designTimeVerticalFieldOfView * Mathf.Deg2Rad;
        hFOVInRads = 2f * Mathf.Atan( Mathf.Tan(vFOVInRads/2f) * aspectRatio);

    }

    void Update () {

        if (Screen.width != prevWidth || Screen.height != prevHeight) { // capture screen ratio changes

            float aspectRatio = (float) Screen.width / (float) Screen.height;

            float vFOVInRads = 2f * Mathf.Atan( Mathf.Tan(hFOVInRads/2f) / aspectRatio );

            Debug.Log("Screen resolution change. Recomputing aspect ratio (" + aspectRatio + ") and field of view (" + vFOVInRads*Mathf.Rad2Deg + ")");

            foreach (Camera cam in GameObject.FindObjectsOfType(typeof(Camera))) {
                cam.fieldOfView = vFOVInRads * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try a SmoothLookAt or transform.LookAt? You can put both on your camera, and specify your board as your "target". You can also do an iTween to make it appear that you are smoothing into looking at a specified target.

```
private var target : Transform;
var damping = 6.0;
var smooth = true;

@script AddComponentMenu("Camera-Control/Smooth Look At")

function LateUpdate () {
    if (target) {
        if (smooth)
        {
            // Look at and dampen the rotation
            var rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(target.position - transform.position);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, rotation, Time.deltaTime * damping);
        }
        else
        {
            // Just lookat
            transform.LookAt(target);
        }
    }
}

function Start () {
    // Make the rigid body not change rotation
    if (target == null)
         target = GameObject.Find("Board_Name").transform;

    if (GetComponent.<Rigidbody>())
        GetComponent.<Rigidbody>().freezeRotation = true;
}
```

With iTween you can use

```
iTween.MoveUpdate(gameObject, iTween.Hash("position",board.position,"time",2));
iTween.LookUpdateModified(gameObject,iTween.Hash("looktarget",board.position,"time",2));
```

There is also a few other camera scripts you could potentially use.

I have also done a mouse Pan Zoom type script a while back. Keep in mind minZoom and maxZoom have to be in between 0 and 180 but you can make it more granular, attach this to Camera and you can control with scroll wheel. I also have touch scripts for Zoom and mobile. This will allow you to zoom in and out.:

```
if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel")!=0) {
    camera.fieldOfView += Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel");
    camera.fieldOfView = Mathf.Clamp(camera.fieldOfView, minZoom, maxZoom);
}
```

Comment: C# not javascript ( see question tags ). Also, i don't want to target any GameObject ( because my board is created dynamically and composed of many other GameObjects ), instead i want my camera to focus on a plane defined as follow `0 < x < 12` and `0 < z < 12` and `y = -1`.

Comment: It's UnityScript, but C# porting shouldn't be so hard. Can you create a centerpoint Instantiate GameObject so you can save it? Or can you Same a Vector3(); statically for access for centerpoint?