# Keep 2 (or more) players in camera

Tags: java, libgdx

Is there a formula for calculating the `x`, `y`, `width`, `height` (viewport) needed to keep two or more points (players) in view at one time.

bonus features:

- A little bit of padding.
- Keeping the aspect ratio (16:9 for example).

I assume there is a formula for this but cannot find anything.

Comment: I found:    


FOV = 2 * arctan((0.5 * distanceBetweenPlayers) / (distanceFromMiddlePoint * aspectRatio));

at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22015697/how-to-keep-2-objects-in-view-at-all-time-by-scaling-the-field-of-view-or-zy

This looks close.

Comment: One screen or a networking game?

Comment: Yea, two players on the same screen

Comment: leftX would be lowest player X - padding; rightX would be highest player X + padding; topY highest player Y + padding; lowY loest player Y - padding; minWidth would be rightX - leftX; minHeight would be topY - lowY; adjust width/height with aspect ratio; center camera on leftX + (rightX-leftX)/2, lowY + (topY-lowY)/2

Comment: Easiest would be to keep one player centered. The other player will be limited to N on X axis and N on Y axis.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it!

to get the camera center position:

```
private Vector2 getCentroid() {
    float centroidX = 0, centroidY = 0;

    for (Player p : players) {
        centroidX += p.getCenter().x;
        centroidY += p.getCenter().y;
    }
    return new Vector2(centroidX / players.size(), centroidY / players.size());
}
```

Then I create a rectangle that goes from the positions of the bottom-left most point to the top-right most point:

```
 private Rectangle getPlayersBounds() {
        float minX = Float.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
        float maxX = Float.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
        float minY = Float.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
        float maxY = Float.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;

        for (Player p : players) {
            if (p.getCenter().x < minX) {
                minX = p.getCenter().x;
            }
            if (p.getCenter().x > maxX) {
                maxX = p.getCenter().x;
            }

            if (p.getCenter().y < minY) {
                minY = p.getCenter().y;
            }
            if (p.getCenter().y > maxY) {
                maxY = p.getCenter().y;
            }

        }
        return new Rectangle(minX, minY, maxX - minX, maxY - minY);
    }
```

I then set camera to the centroid position and use the rectangle to determine how far the players are out of the screen and zoom out by that.

```
private void updateCameraPosition() {
        camera.position.set(getCentroid(), 0);


        Rectangle playersBounds = getPlayersBounds();

        float xxx = playersBounds.getWidth() / Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
        float yyy = playersBounds.getHeight() / Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

        float biggest = Math.max(xxx, yyy);

        camera.zoom = Math.max(1, biggest);

    }
```